# Bootstrap 2.3.2 type-head is not allowing me to enter '&' once drop down menu display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 type-heed in my project . the input type-head field is allowing me to enter "&" character for the first time. But when the auto complete drop down is displaying the input field is not allowing me to enter "&" character.

just went to below link and type "&" first time and remove .

Again type any character and type "&" character beside of 'A'.

[**Boostarp 2.3.2 typehead Link**](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead)

Comment: post a sample of your code here

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast: I was unable to post code , but the link which I provided in question it will directly take you to type-head section of bootstrap page. there you can try in Chrome and IE browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because charCode for "ampersand" is 38 and charCode(ASCII) for up arrow is also 38.
And bootstrap rejects this value internally and shows the previous value.